# Print results of a SELECT query as preformatted text in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for an easy and quick way to print out the results of a MySQL SELECT query in PHP as preformatted text. What I would like is to be able to pass a query object to a function and get a printout of the recordset like the command line MySQL client does when running SELECT statements.

Here is an example of how I want it to look (i.e. ASCII):

```
+----+-------------+
| id | countryCode |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | ES          |
|  2 | AN          |
|  3 | AF          |
|  4 | AX          |
|  5 | AL          |
|  6 | DZ          |
|  7 | AS          |
|  8 | AD          |
|  9 | AO          |
| 10 | AI          |
+----+-------------+
```

It's basically for a generic import script, I am doing a SELECT query and want to display the results to the user for confirmation.

Comment: why do you want an ASCII output.  Using a table with CSS styling would be much easier.

Comment: Becuase I was hoping there would be a simple function to print the result in ASCII form as MySQL client does this already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[sprintf](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)  is your friend, if you must have a non-HTML fixed width output.

ETA:

```
//id: integer, max width 10
//code: string max width 2

$divider=sprintf("+%-10s+%-13s+",'-','-');

$lines[]=$divider;
$lines[]=sprintf("|%10s|%13s|",'id','countryCode'); //header
$lines[]=$divider;

while($line=$records->fetch_assoc()) {
    //store the formatted output
    $lines[]=sprintf("| %10u | %2.2s |", $line['id'],$line['code']);
}
$table=implode("\n",$lines);
echo $table;
```

If you want to print out immediately instead of storing the results, use `printf` instead- same syntax. There is a reasonable PHP (s)printf tutorial [here](http://www.elated.com/articles/formatting-php-strings-printf-sprintf/).

Comment: Can you explain how I can get the table printed using sprintf?

Comment: @Camsoft, I've added a relevant example.

Comment: That's great. I'm having a few formatting issues but I think these can be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

```
function formatResults($cols, $rows) {
    echo'<table>';
    echo '<tr>';

    foreach ($cols as $v) {
        echo '<th>' . $v['field'] . '</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    foreach ($rows as $sRow) {
        echo '<tr>';

        foreach ($sRow as $v) {
            echo "<td>$v</td>";
        }

        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}

$qry = $pdo->query('DESCRIBE table');
$cols = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$pdo->query('SELECT * FROM table');
$rows = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

formatResults($cols, $rows);
```

Untested but should work.

**Edit:** Missed ['field'] index ;)

Comment: Just enable table borders, and maybe spit out a little CSS to customize the <th> headers if you want (I often use a background color on headers).

Comment: Of course, you can strip out the HTML table elements and replace with sprintf() statements as dnagirl suggested if you really must have plain text.

Comment: If you *do* go for HTML, you need to `htmlspecialchars()` every value you put in the `<td>`​s and `<th>`​s.