# Run queries through the website

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to run queries through my website(online) and managed to do it with INSERT , DELETE and UPDATE but I've got some problems with SELECT... Not sure how to print the result. Here what I tried:

```
$execute = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$res = mysqli_fetch_array($execute);
foreach($res as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key.' '.$value.'<br>';
}
```

That prints only one row..
also tried:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute))
```

but still nothing.So let's say for example i've got a table `users` with ~50 rows and columns - `id`, `name` and `username`. And when I run:

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

I want to print everything from that table.
Can someone help me with that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print results of a SELECT query as preformatted text in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639345/print-results-of-a-select-query-as-preformatted-text-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<?php
$execute = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($recSet = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)) {
   echo $recSet['id'].' - '.$recSet['name'].' - '.$recSet['username'];
}
```

Comment: Nope.. Someone gave me a solution but deleted his comment dunno why and it worked:
                   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)) { 
                        foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
                            echo $key.' '.$value.'<br>';
                            } 
                        }